# Integrative Genome Browser can't find Java Runtime

Tags: java, high-sierra

Every time I try to run IGV, I'm greeted with can't find Java Runtime error dialog. I have Java installed on the system as running `/usr/libexec/java_home` returns `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home`. I also have the `JAVA_HOME` variable set to the above value (though the value is not included in my PATH).

The `java` command is also accessible through command line so I don't see any reason why the application can't access it. Running `java -version` returns `1.8.0_05`.

I believe I also have the legacy Apple Java 6 installed although the preference pane for that is not available (maybe something wrong here?) and I don't know how to verify its installation.

I'm on 10.13 High Sierra.

*** Update
Running `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` shows that both Java 6 and 8 are installed:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.8.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you running Igv?

Comment: Also does IGV require a specific version of Java?

Comment: @Mark double clicking the .app downloaded from their website.

Comment: Clcicking on apps runs things from the Finder which does not look at any environment variables in the shell. What does IGV documentation say

Comment: @Mark It [says](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/download) drop the app somewhere and double click it. It probably looks for Java in some default directory which doesn't match the one on my system.

Comment: BTW that Java 8 version is very old - Java 8 is on version 152

Comment: Reading http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/startingIGV there is no app file - try starting from the command line